# Firefox not responding to mixin

Tags: css, firefox, sass

Firefox 31.0 does not respond to border-radius when using sass mixin but when i explicitly add border-radius: 50%, i get the correct result.

```
@mixin vendor($property, $value, $vendors) {
  @each $vendor in $vendors {
    @if ($vendor == 'webkit') {
      -webkit-#{$property}: $value;
    }

    @if ($vendor == 'moz') {
      -moz-#{$property}: $value;
    }

    @if ($vendor == 'ms') {
      -ms-#{$property}: $value;
    }

    @if ($vendor == 'o') {
      -o-#{$property}: $value;
    }

    @if ($vendor == 'official') {
      $property: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Then the class looks like this.

```
 .social-btn {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      @include vendor(border-radius, 50%, webkit moz o official);
      background: $color-primary;
      display: inline-block;
      color: $color-white;
      font-size: 1.429rem;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      &:hover, &:focus {
        background: $color-green;
        color: $color-white;
      }
    }
```

I can't find any error.

**EDIT**

Firefox output looks like this

```
.organiser-profile .company-info .social-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #242830;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.429rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Chrome output

```
.organiser-profile .company-info .social-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  background: #242830;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.429rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What does the CSS that gets sent to the browser look like?

Comment: I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: Please show the actual _code_ the browser receives – not what it shows _after_ interpretation of that code.

Comment: Looking at the DOM inspector is useless:  they typically discard properties/values they don't understand.  You need to be looking at the source of the generated CSS file to see if it's generating what you expect before you jump straight to "it doesn't work in browser X".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
@if ($vendor == 'official') {
  $property: $value;
}
```

All you're doing is setting `$property` to whatever you passed in as `$value`.  You need to use interpolation:

```
@if ($vendor == 'official') {
  #{$property}: $value;
}
```